# Linearly independent matrix in python

Tags: python, linear-algebra

I have a matrix which is 15714 x 541 and it seems that this matrix is not linearly independent. How can I remove columns that are not linearly independent?

I tried using this solution from this post:
[elimination the linear dependent columns of a non-square matrix in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53667174/elimination-the-linear-dependent-columns-of-a-non-square-matrix-in-python)

But, it says:
ValueError: Item wrong length 541 instead of 15714.

```
Q, R = np.linalg.qr(fixeff.T)
fixeff[np.abs(np.diag(R))>=1e-10]
```

fixeff is matrix that I described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with `scipy.linalg.qr`:

```
from scipy.linalg import qr

Q, R, P = qr(A, mode="economic", pivoting=True)
inv = P.argsort() # reversed order (necessary here)
good_columns = (np.abs(np.diag(R)) > 1e-10)[inv]

A = A[:,good_columns]
```